# Dailymotion thumbnail large

Tags: video, thumbnails, dailymotion-api

I'm using this code for now to display DailyMotion video thumbnail on my site:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="200" height="114" data={{'http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/' ~ video.lien}}">
<param name="movie" value="{{'http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/' ~ video.lien }}" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

The thing is that it provides me a 4/3 ratio image and I need a 16/9 image. Does someone know how to get it?

In the code I'm using `ht..//thumbnail/video/x23dkq` and this URL sends back: `s2.dmcdn.net/NHFw/320x240-pDT.jpg` which is the 4/3 thumbnail.

I've seen on DailyMotion the thumbnail I need is `s2.dmcdn.net/GVKs/220x123-7mU.jpg`, but I don't know how to call it.

Comment: did you find how to get it? It is possible using their API. Is there any other way? Here is the api.
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x23dkq?fields=thumbnail_large_url

Answer (score 4):

Why do you embed an image in flash object ?

Anyway you can get 16/9 thumbnails like this :

```
 https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=id,thumbnail_360_url,title&thumbnail_ratio=widescreen
```

Use the API Explorer : http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/explorer#/video/ if you want to try